# How do I re-attach my kitchen cabinet's laminate?

Tags: cabinets, adhesive, laminate

Steam from my electric kettle has caused the veneer of one of my kitchen cabinets to separate from the doors and I need to stick it back on.

1. What is the best method to use? Should I peel the veneer all the way off, sand and then re-glue it on? Or would I be better off keeping it in place and gluing it down as-is?
2. What adhesive should I use? There's nowhere in my kitchen I can put my kettle where it isn't going to be under a cabinet, so the glue would ideally be steam/heat resistant.

I was thinking about getting a spray adhesive and applying it under the veneer without completely removing it but I'm thinking that it may not be a lasting fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue happen with my dishwasher and counter top laminate.  What I ended up doing is peeling it back a bit more to give me access, and picked up some laminate/veneer cement (it is similar to rubber cement).  You apply to both the laminate and the substrate, let it dry for 15 minutes (until it is no longer glossy) then push the two pieces together.  In my case, I was able to line the underside of the countertop with a sheet of poly, which has kept the steam from the dishwasher from working its way up through the particle board substrate.

Comment: If you look closely under the laminate, you will likely see small bits of the substrate are still adhered to the original glue. The glue didn't fail, the substrate did. Few materials can resist steam in the long run. After your repair, do what you can to pull the kettle out from under the cabinet and direct the spout away from it as well. Otherwise the substrate will fail again.

Comment: I ended up using some spray-on contact adhesive, I peeled it back without detaching it completely, sprayed it in, waited for it to get tacky, then pressed it down. Not a bad fix, although the contact adhesive got pressed out of the seams and made a mess.

Comment: What is a sheet of poly? Any other names for it that can be found a bit easier?  Thanks

Comment: Poly is short for polyethylene Sheeting, aka plastic sheeting.  It is the same material that is stapled to the studs in your walls to create a vapor barrier.  You can pick it up at most hardware/big-box stores.  Something like a 6-8mil thickness would work well for this type of application.